# How to force schtasks to return messages in English

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

I'm using a tool schtask to do some scheduled tasks management (under win xp, 7, 2008) (mainly  I need list of scheduled task). I query it from my code and parse messages returned by it. Recently I stumble upon a problem because on NON English systems this tool returns messages in language different than English. Unfortunately I need this messages in English. Is there a way to force this tool to return messages in English ? Maybe there is some alternative tool / method to do it?

Comment: Is this different than the MS schtasks.exe?  If it's coded to use the locale of the machine it's running on, then most likely you're not going to get it to return output in English.

Comment: No it is the same as schtasks.exe